# How to install PyDev 2.8.2 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, installation, pydev

I want to install `PyDev 2.8.2` in Eclipse because my Eclipse version is too old for `3.x.x` compatibility. However by using the update site `http://pydev.org/updates` and having ***unchecked*** the box "Show only the latest versions ...", only 3.4.1 is showing up and I can't seen any 2.8.2.

I use Ubuntu and would like to know how to install 2.8.2.

I do not currenlty have any version installed.

Answer (score 3):

The [pydeve.org/updates](http://www.pydev.org/updates) URL/site only hosts the newest version of pydev. If you need to install a different version you need to change the URL to one from  http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/.

they are structured like http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/#.#.#

Answer (score 1):

The link http://pydev.org/updates is just a re-direction to where the update site is now hosted, it appears.

Try with http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates

Also, make sure 'Show only latest version...' option is unchecked in the Install New Software wizard.

Answer (score 1):

First download Pydev 2.8.2 version and put pydev 2.8.2 in eclipse-home/Addons.Next Restart your eclipse.Go to window---> preference you see pydev software.